# Maximum number of pairs from list elements satisfying at least a minimum value difference

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Given a list `l` of length `n` (e.g. `n=1000`) with (random) integer elements in the range `0<l[i]<10^m` (e.g. `m=5`), what is the maximum number of pairs of two elements one can extract from this list (no element in one pair may overlap with any element in another pair), such that each element pair has at least a minimum difference of their values `0<=diff<10^k` with `0<k<=m`?

The naïve approach of generating all possible partitions and checking each for the largest number of pairs with sufficient distance in values is very inefficient. How could we do this in a smart way?

EXAMPLE:

Consider list `l` to be given by:

```
l = {1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 15};
```

and the minimum difference between elements in admissible pairs `diff=7`. Then we can construct the following sets of disjoint pairs satisfying the element distance requirements:

```
{ {1,8} , {2,9} }

{ {1,8} , {2,10} }

{ {1,8} , {2,15} }

{ {1,9} , {2,10} , {8,15} }

{ {1,9} , {2,15} }

{ {1,10} , {2,9} , {8,15} }

...etc
```

Note that all pairs selected have elements such that `larger element` minus `smaller element` is bigger or equal to the minimum value `diff=7` as required. In the above example, as soon as we encounter a case where the maximum number of pairs (e.g. `3`) can be built, we can stop, since we found out that the answer is `3`. But it may happen that a list only admits a maximal number of such pairs that is less than half of the length of `l`. List `l` also may have multiple elements with the same value, in which case combinations involving one are not equivalent to numerically same combinations involving the other (but presumably their number of pairs will be the same).

Comment: It will help if you provide an example.

Comment: @Damien I have now included an example.

Comment: According to your example, the difference of each pair is greater than `k`, not lower...

Comment: @Damien Yes, exactly, the minimum difference of the elements must be `diff`, as per problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If each element may appear in any number of pairs

There are (n choose 2) pairs in total, so the number of pairs with difference at least `diff` is equal to (n choose 2) minus the number of pairs with difference less than `diff`.

Counting those is easier: sort the array, and use a two-pointer technique where `i < j` are the indices of a possible pair, starting with `i = 0` and `j = 1`. When the difference is small enough, increment `j`; when the difference is too large, then increment `i`, and add `j - i` to the total to account for pairs where the smaller value is at index `i`. (By incrementing first, we avoid counting the pair where the difference is too large.)

Since every iteration either increments `i` or `j`, and neither index ever gets smaller for any reason, the total number of operations in the "counting" phase is O(n). Therefore, the overall time complexity is O(n log n) for sorting the array in the first place.

### If each element may only occur in one pair

Again, sorting helps a lot with this.

- If `(a, b)` is a pair, then any element `c < a` also appears in a pair, otherwise swapping `a` and `c` would still result in a valid pair.
- If `(a, b)` is a pair, then any element `d > b` also appears in a pair, otherwise swapping `b` and `d` would still result in a valid pair.
- If `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` are both pairs, then `b >= c`, otherwise swapping `b` and `c` would still result in two valid pairs.
- If `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` are both pairs and `a <= c`, then also `b <= d`, otherwise swapping `b` and `d` would still result in two valid pairs.

It follows that if there is a solution with `k` pairs, then there is a solution where the smallest `k` elements are paired with the largest `k` elements in the same order. So we only need to look for such solutions, by finding the largest number `k` such that all of the differences are large enough.

Note that finding the largest such `k` is not as simple as the two-pointer technique, for example in the array `1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9` with minimum difference `4`, the solution given by this method is `(1, 7), (4, 9)`, but the differences `(1, 6)` and `(5, 9)` are both large enough. A simple approach would just be to check all of the differences for each `k`, resulting in an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, which should be totally fine for `n = 1000`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm so sorry! Now I feel a bit embarrassed, since I likely did not describe the problem very well. What I meant to ask is what is the maximum number of such simultaneous pairs that can be extracted from this list (where no two pairs have any overlap in the element indices they refer to in the original list). Is that the question this answer targets, or counting the maximum number of ways to extract a single such pair from the list (which is not actually what I want)? I will edit my question to attempt to make it more precise.

Comment: I see, so the pairs have to not reuse elements from other pairs. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I'm really curious if this can be done quicker than O(n^2), though...

Comment: You could do a binary search looking for the largest `k` that works, that should make it O(n log n) since each possible value of `k` takes O(n) time to check and you should only need to try O(log n) candidates. But for n = 1000 I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks again! You are probably describing exactly the same approach used in the following statement and solution of the problem. Problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1156/problem/C Solution editorial: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/66827